# Nix maintain original order of a set

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nix, yq

Assumptions:
You have `yq` and `nix` installed on your OS running NixOS or some Linux distro.

Question:
Can nix maintain the original ordering of a set? i.e. If I create a sample.nix file:

```
{pkgs}:
let
dockerComposeConfig = {
    version = "1.0";
    services = {
        srv1 = { name = "srv1"; };
        srv2 = { name = "srv2"; };
    };
};
in writeTextFile {
    name = "docker-compose.json";
    text = builtins.toJSON dockerComposeConfig;

}
```

When I build and convert the output to yaml below I notice is that the set has been alphabetized by Nix. Is there a workaround that keeps my JSON in the same ordering as intended by a Docker user such that the `dockerComposeConfig attrributes remain in the order they are created?

```
# Cmd1
nix-build -E "with import <nixpkgs> {}; callPackage ./sample.nix {}"

# Cmd2
cat /nix/store/SOMEHASH-docker-compose.json | yq r - --prettyPrint
```

Comment: Did you see Arion? https://github.com/hercules-ci/arion/  It can also be used as a Nix function with `arion.eval`.

Answer (score 2):

Nix attribute sets don't have an ordering to their attributes and they are represented as a sorted array in memory. Canonicalizing values helps with reproducibility.

If it's really important you could write a function that turns a list of key value pairs into a JSON object as a Nix string. But that's not going to be easy to use like `builtins.toJSON`. I'd consider the JSON as "compiled build output" and not worry too much about aesthetics.

Side note: Semantically, they are not even created in any order. The Nix language is declarative: a Nix expression (excluding derivations) describes something that is, not how to create it, although it may be defined in terms of functions.
This is necessary for Nix's laziness to be effective.